# uploading photos to cloud from an infected device

Tags: malware, cloud-computing, backup

My computer is infected with Malware and (shame on me) of course I didn't back up my photos or word docs. I also happen to know almost NOTHING about computers. Is it possible to upload photos to cloud now without spreading the virus/malware infection or not worth the risk? external hard drive an option?

Comment: Is the cloud already virus free?

Answer (score 2):

It's always possible that any files on an infected machine are infected themselves, but I'd say that image files are a less common target for malware.

One approach would be to upload them to a cloud service and then make sure that you scan them with an A-V solution when you re-download them.

Whether it's worth the risk to you will depend on how much you want the pictures :)